# Mongoose save error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below there is a sample code I copied from a website. I am trying to save information to mongodb. I have tried similar answers around stack overflow but still cannot solve it.

When I run it and write id, name and age save method fails but gives no error message. What can the reason be? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set("view engine", 'jade');

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
//app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../public'));
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//    res.render('index', {});
//});


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"));
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id    : String,
name: String,
age   : Number
});

var user = mongoose.model('emp', Schema);



app.get('/view', function(req, res){
user.find({}, function(err, docs){
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else    res.render('index', {users: docs});
    });
});


app.post('/new', function(req, res){
new user({
    _id    : req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    age   : req.body.age
    }).save(function(err){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.send('Successfully inserted!');
        });
    });



var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you change your schema to this:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  name: String,
  age: Number
});
```

I would also recommend changing the model from "emp" to just be "user". Or all the vars from "user" to "emp". Being consistent is more readable and will save you time later down the road. Also it looks like you are missing the: `require('jade')` at the top.

You can query by email to find a user. Mongo will automatically generate an _id on insert.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you! Gotta be careful.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.